# instagram feed on website

Tags: instagram, feed

I'm trying to display an Instagram feed on my website. I am not familiar with server side scripts. The explanations I have read go over my head.

I have managed to get an access key through Instagram but I don't know how to proceed.

I also tried the instructions from a video "How to implement an Instagram Feed in PHP without using the Instagram API"

For that, my php file works, displays the feed but I don't understand how to make it appear on my html page.

I'd be happy to make either method work.

Comment: Show what you've coded so far, please.  That makes it easier for people to isolate where a flaw may have occurred.  Consider reading [ask] and come back to [edit], providing a [mcve] of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you should include a JavaScript 'script' element where you do something called an AJAX Request. The request will access the PHP file that produces the Instagram feed. ECHO the result from the PHP file and it will be returned into the DATA variable in the AJAX request. The request looks roughly like this:

```
                $.ajax({
                     method: ‘POST or GET, most likely POST’,
                      url:  ‘not always an actual url, this is the path to your PHP file’,
                      success: function(data) {
                         //php file returns into variable ‘data’
                        //display the feed within this function
                      }
                    });
```

The result from the PHP file should be echo’d back in JSON notation, if it isn’t, just add this to end of PHP the file:

```
   $whatever = json_encode($your_result);
   echo $whatever; //this is still the feed, just encoded in JSON
```

And if you need to decode it for some reason, just do

```
   json_decode($variable_to_decode);
```

There are other parameters you can use in the AJAX request, like if for instance you need access to certain variables in your PHP file, that currently only exist in your HTML document.

Comment: here is what i put in the html:

<div class="instagram-feed"></div>
<script>
  $(function(){
   console.log('Fetching instagram feed');
   $.ajax({
    url: "/instagram_feed",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data){
     $(".instagram-feed .row").append(data);
     $(".instagram-feed .row .loading.spinner").remove();
    }
   });
  });
 </script>

that is the script used in the video i referenced. can you tell based on this code what the php file should be called and where it is located?

Comment: First, change your <script> to <script type="text/javascript">, HTML won't automatically recognize it as JavaScript. Have the METHOD come before URL, also, you can call the PHP file anything you want. If the the HTML file is in the same directory as the PHP file, then the URL should look like this "/name_of_file.php". If the HTML file is the 'parent' of the directory where the PHP file is, then the URL becomes "/name_of_sub_directory/name_of_file.php"

Comment: thanks, i tried adding <script type="text/javascript"> and adding .php to the url but still not coming up.

Answer (score -1):

this was solved by saving the html as php. i don't know why that is but it worked

Comment: Yor need to give an answer for the question despite writing a comment as the answer.